# System of equations with insufficient equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of equations problem with $5$ variables but only $4$ equations:

Suppose that $x,y,z,u$ and $v$ are real numbers that satisfy the following system:
$$
\begin{align}
-4x + 6y + 14z     + 4v &= -8\\
-3x + 9y + 15z - u + 3v &= 6\\
-3x      +  6z + u + 3v &= -18\\
-x + 2y + 4z       + v &= -1\\
\end{align}
$$
Which of the following statements are true?

i. $y + z = 2$

ii. $v = 0$

iii. $x - 2z - v = 5$

iv. $y + z - u = 5$

Ans: The correct statements are: **__**

A. i. and iii.

B. i., ii., and iii.

C. i., iii., and iv.

D. i. and ii.

E. All

**How should I approach the problem considering there are more variables than equations?**

Comment: Irrespective of numbers of variables and equations, a way to approach such problems is to set up the augmented matrix representing the system of equations and then use elementary row operations to bring it to reduced row-echelon form; from there it will probably be easy to see what the answer is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build the matrix of the system and apply Gaussian elimination:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
−4 & 6 & 14 & 0 & 4 & −8\\
−3 & 9 & 15 & −1 & 3 & 6\\
−3 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 3 & −18\\
−1 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 1 &−1
\end{array}\right]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
−1 & 2 & 4 & 0 & 1 &−1 \\
−4 & 6 & 14 & 0 & 4 & −8\\
−3 & 9 & 15 & −1 & 3 & 6\\
−3 & 0 & 6 & 1 & 3 & −18
\end{array}\right]\text{ (swap 1 and 4)}\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1 & -2 & -4 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & -2 & 0 & 0 & −4\\
0 & 3 & 3 & −1 & 0 & 9\\
0 & -6 & -6 & 1 & 0 & −15
\end{array}\right]\text{ (first column)}\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1 & -2 & -4 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & −1 & 0 & 3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & −3
\end{array}\right]\text{ (second column)}\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1 & -2 & -4 & 0 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\text{ (fourth column)}\\
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
1 & 0 & -2 & 0 & -1 & 5 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & -3\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]\text{ (second column)}\\
\end{align}

Your system has been reduced to the form
\begin{cases}
x=2z+v+5\\
y=-z+2\\
u=-3
\end{cases}
Can you answer the questions now?

Comment: Yes thanks! I was worried it had something to do with infinite equations. This is elegantly done, thanks.